# How to refer to a Java .properties file from .xml configuration file (JSF)?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsf, jsf-2

Is there an easy way to specify in a JSF configuration .xml file (for example, faces-config.xml, web.xml or applicationContext.xml) that I would like to retrieve certain values for the configuration from an external .properties file?  is that something that can be done using JNDI or similar?

For example:

```
<something>
#{brilliant-code-that-retrieves-values-from-.properties-file}
</something>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is; in JSF, it's done using Resource Bundles.

**Vanilla Implementation**

1. Start with your garden variety `.properties`  file

   ```
   currency.symbol = "$"
   currency.name = "dollar"
   ```
2. Define a resource bundle in your *faces.config.xml* file

   ```
   <resource-bundle>
       <base-name>com.you.resources.info</base-name>
       <var>paymentInfo</var>
   </resource-bundle>
   ```
3. Refer to your resource bundle (which is handled by the context as a managed object) in your faces-config.xml. Bear in mind that the faces-config.xml file also processes EL; for all intents and purposes, any EL you place in there would be scanned like it were in a view :

   ```
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>YourManagedBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>
            com.you.app.BeanClass
        </managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>currencyName</property-name>
            <value>#{paymentInfo['currency.name']}</value>
       </managed-property>
       </managed-bean-name>
    </managed-bean>
   ```

**Loading a property file configured in a spring context**

Spring provide property file loading out of the box using the `util` namespace (`xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"`). Using the same config file:

1. Define a configurer in your applicationContext.xml

   ```
    <util:properties id="paymentInfo" location="classpath:com/you/resources/info/payment-info.properties" />
   ```
2. You can use the bean `#{paymentInfo}` just like you would in #3 above in either your faces-config.xml or applicationContext.xml

Comment: OP asked how to access it in a configuration XML file not how to access it in a JSF view.

Comment: Ah, now I see @BalusC

Answer (score 1):

**For web.xml:**

Simply put a context param in there

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>something</param-name>
    <param-value>#{brilliant-code-that-retrieves-values-from-.properties-file}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Retrieve that param in your code somewhere any way you like e.g. via CDI in a bean and then evaluate that retrieved `String` as an expression. E.g. with

```
@Inject   
private ServletContext context;

public MySomething getMySomething() {

    final String mySomethingString = context.getInitParameter("something");
    final ELContext elCtx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
    (MySomething) mySomething = (MySomething) child.getValueExpression().getValue(elCtx);    
    return mySomething;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I retrieve a .properties file value and use it in an xml configuration file?  I think your example retrieves a context param value and uses it in .java code instead.